# How to unbind viewModel from activity when it's destroying

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have my miewModel, which I'm injecting to my fragment throw `ViewModelProviders.of(activity, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)`.

It's work fine on first time of fragment creation, but if I will close my fragment, then I'will get an error "`layout must not be null`" which points on some of my layouts which I'm using in my fragment.

As I understood, this ishue happend because databinding still have some links to my fragment. So how to unbind it?

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(), Injectable {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory 

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        activity?.window?.changeStatusBarColor(this.requireContext(), R.color.yellow_status_bar)

        val binding: MyLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_layout, container, false)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        viewModel.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(object : Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            override fun onPropertyChanged(sender: Observable?, propertyId: Int) {
}
}
```

ViewModelModule:

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
internal abstract fun bindMyViewModel(myViewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bound `ViewModel` life cycle to fragment you need to call:

```
val vm = ViewModelProviders.of(fragnemt, viewModelFactory)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

instead of:

```
val vm = ViewModelProviders.of(activity, viewModelFactory)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

Don't forget to release resources in `ViewModel.onCleared()`